# Nil in CanCan initialize parameter in ability.rb model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, cancan

I'm following the tutorial from Ryan B, but I got something wrong when trying to inspect the user's role.

Why I got a nil initialize parameter when I inspect it. Are there any connection between the initialize parameter with the Person Object, in Ryan's tutorial is using 'user' parameter on initialize method and User Model. Am I forgetting something basic here? These are my codes, Thanks!

```
class Ability 
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(person)
    raise person.inspect
    can :read, :all
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely there is no logged in user when you are running this code. You need to create some sort of guest user to check permissions against non logged in users

```
  def initialize(person)
    user ||= User.new
    if user.role? :somerole
      can :read, :all
    else
     #whatever guest can do
    end
  end
```

Comment: That, or you can also test for person.nil? to assign guest rights.

Comment: I tested it when I logged in as administrator, but still get nil value. Am I have to install AuthLogic first for combine with CanCan? I just guess, if we know the user status from session so that we can add the role with CanCan? But, if it can, how can I get the session data in model?

Comment: Solved, in the README file is written that I have to override the current_ability method if I use a different user object. Thanks David Sulc.